# Adicionar texto ao input (teclado virtual)

Tags: jquery

Elaborei o seguinte script:

```
<input type="password" class="email password_action" placeholder="Account Password" id="user_password"  name="user_password" required>
<? for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){ ?>
    <button id="keyboard_<?=$i;?>" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="<?=$i;?>"><?=$i?></button>
    <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var valueKey = $('#keyboard_<?=$i;?>');

            valueKey.click(function(){
                //$("#user_password").attr("value",valueKey.val());
                $('#user_password').append($('#user_password').attr(valueKey.val()));
                alert(valueKey.val());
            });
        });
    </script>
<? } ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que ao clicar no botão que se refere ao número para inserir a senha, ele não adiciona no campo password.

Como eu faço para que clicando em qualquer um dos números apresentados dentro do for, adicione o valor do button ao input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer usando javascript para adicionar o valor do botão ao campo definido como id="user_password":

```js
function moveNumbers(num) { 
    var txt=document.getElementById("user_password").value; 
    txt=txt + num; 
    document.getElementById("user_password").value=txt; 
}
```

```html
<input type="password" class="email password_action" placeholder="Account Password" id="user_password"  name="user_password" required><p>
<input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">
```

Exemplo funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/hiperportal/zga8r4pz/

Comment: Bom dia, e pra adicionar um botão de "backspace" junto?

Comment: Se eu colocar um alert(txt), ele vem os numeros conforme forem pressionados, mas não preenche o campo

Comment: Deu certo, mudei o nome do campo e funcionou de boa! Vou postar o script completo. Caso alguém precise.

Comment: Desculpe, só voltei agora, que bom que conseguiu :D

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém precise, estou postando a solução completa com base na resposta do nosso amigo Wesley

```
<div class="controls">
    <input id="userpassword"  placeholder="Account Password" class="email" name="userpassword" type="password" readonly="" required/>
    <? for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){ ?>
        <input type="button" value="<?=$i?>" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)" class="btn btn-default">  
    <? } ?>
        <input type="button" value="«" name="backspace" onclick="moveNumbers(this.name)" class="btn btn-default"> 
</div>


<script>
    function moveNumbers(num) { 
        var txt=document.getElementById("userpassword").value; 
        if(num=='backspace'){
            var width = $('#userpassword').val().length-1;
            var text_ad = $('#userpassword').val();
            var text_ad_out = text_ad.substring(0,width);
            $('#userpassword').val(text_ad_out);
        } else {
            txt=txt + num; 
            document.getElementById("userpassword").value=txt; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]